# who deletes object created in worker thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt

In my code, worker thread creates object A, main thread class B destructor calls worker thread’s destructor, object A is deleted in worker thread’s destructor.
the code is like:

```
WorkerThread::foo() {
Object *p = new Object;
}

WorkerThread::~WorkerThread {
delete p;
wait();
}

B::~B() {
emit signal(); 
//this signal is to ask worker thread to quit, 
//the signal/slot connection is connect(this, SIGNAL), mWorkerThread, SLOT));
delete mWorkerThread;
}
```

Now the problem is worker thread’s other function may be still using *p (object A). I know I can add mutex at WorkerThread destructor. But sometimes I got error message saying that object A should not be deleted in the thread which didn’t not create it. Does this mean I need to delete *p in worker thread? how do I make it work? use another signal and slot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If possible, create and destroy the object right in the `run()` function of the thread.

If the object must exist in calling thread (Qt likes widgets to live on the main thread for example), then create it in constructor of your thread object (or pass it in) and delete in destructor like you do now (this assuming your thread would be destroyed by caller thread after it is done).

Also, after emitting the kill signal, `join()` the thread before deleting it, to make sure it finished cleanly.